# Alter table name if insert query execution is completed

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I want to execute the following queries into the same order (step1, step2 and step3).

**Problem:**

The insert query in step2 is taking more time to complete the insert. Because of this alter rename query is failing.

STEP 1: Creating a table structure like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_summary` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
`app_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`datetimes` datetime NOT NULL,      
KEY `date` (`date`),
KEY `app_id` (`app_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

STEP 2: Fill the table using this query

```
INSERT INTO app_summary(date, app_id, datetimes) 
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(job.datetimes, '+00:00', '+05:30'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates,
        job.app_id,
        MAX(job.datetimes) AS datetimes  
    FROM 
        ijob AS job
    WHERE 1
    GROUP BY 
        dates, app_id
    ORDER BY 
        NULL
```

STEP 3: Rename the table

```
ALTER TABLE app_summary RENAME TO summary;
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: how many records you have in ijob table?

Comment: It contains a CRORE data

Comment: have you heard about trigger.?

Comment: yeah I know that.. I'll try to play

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar is it possible to execute the trigger without for each row condition alter query is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can use to try and solve your problem is [**mysqli_multi_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

This might be more of a hack. My other option is to check once the `INSERT` returns the number of rows affect using:

```
if ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0){
    //RUN THE RENAME QUERY
}
else {
    //TRY THE INSERT AGAIN.
}
```

If the `$mysqli->affected_rows > 0` then you can execute the rename section else try running `INSERT` again. all in all you should see if you can't improve the performance of the tables and mysql server itself when working with suc large inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You code should look like:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE....';
mysqli_($sql);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ...';
mysqli_query( $sql );
$sql = 'ALTER TABLE ...';
mysqli_query( $sql );
```

This way they follow each other.

You can speed up the inserts be removing the 2 KEY statements and re-instate them with the ALTER statement.

Comment: This will fail because of large data in insert query

Comment: OK - then do it in a mysql procedure this way you could set timers on this procedure if you needed to repeat the process at regular intervals.